# Initial default state is not showing, displaying empty

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

This is from a tutorial assignment from Dave Ceddia's Redux course, I am trying to display the initial state, which contains an array of objects, however it is simply returning undefined and not displaying anything. I am new to React, and I have hit a wall on getting 1) my buttons to display the state, and 2) default state to appear initially.

I have tried to have my component `Buttons` as a class, and constant. 
I have tried stating my `initialReducer` in the `default: return state;` in my reducer as well. I have also tried different syntax for my dispatch actions, but nothing seems to be getting to the reducer.

index.js

```
import React, { Fragment } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import { getAllItems, addEventToBeginning, addEventToEnd } from "./actions";
import { connect, Provider } from "react-redux";
import { store } from "./reducers";

const Buttons = ({
  state,
  getAllItems,
  addEventToBeginning,
  addEventToEnd
}) => (
  <React.Fragment>
    <ul>{state ? state.actions.map(item => <li>{item}</li>) : []}</ul>
    <button onClick={getAllItems}> Display items </button>
    <button onClick={addEventToBeginning}> addEventToBeginning </button>
    <button onClick={addEventToEnd}> addEventToEnd </button>
  </React.Fragment>
);

const mapDispatchToProps = { getAllItems, addEventToBeginning, addEventToEnd };

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  actions: state.actions,
  sum: state.sum
});

connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  mapDispatchToProps
)(Buttons);
```

reducers.js

```
const initialState = {
  actions: [
    { id: 0, type: "SALE", value: 3.99 },
    { id: 1, type: "REFUND", value: -1.99 },
    { id: 2, type: "SALE", value: 17.49 }
  ],
  sum: 0
};
```

```
const newUnit = { id: Math.random * 10, type: "SALE", value: Math.random * 25 };

function eventReducer(state = initialState, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case ADD_EVENT_TO_BEGINNING:
      const copy = { ...state };
      copy.actions.unshift(newUnit);
      return copy;
    case ADD_EVENT_TO_END:
      const copy2 = { ...state };
      copy2.actions.unshift(newUnit);
      return copy2;
```

cut out for cleanliness

```
    case GET_ITEMS:
      return {
        ...state,
        actions: state.actions,
        sum: state.sum
      };
    default:
      return state;
  }
}

export const store = createStore(eventReducer);
```

example of actions.js (they all follow same format)

```
export const ADD_EVENT_TO_BEGINNING = "ADD_EVENT_TO_BEGINNING";

export function addEventToBeginning() {
  return dispatch => {
    dispatch({
      type: ADD_EVENT_TO_BEGINNING
    });
  };
}
```

UPDATE:

Thank you @ravibagul91 and @Yurui_Zhang, I cut everything but getAllItems out, and changed the state to:

```
const initialState = {
  itemsById: [
    { id: 0, type: "SALE", value: 3.99 },
    { id: 1, type: "REFUND", value: -1.99 },
    { id: 2, type: "SALE", value: 17.49 }
  ]
};
```

```
class Form extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {this.props.itemsById
          ? this.props.itemsById.map(item => (
              <li>
                {item.id} {item.type} {item.value}
              </li>
            ))
          : []}
        <button onClick={this.getAllItems}> Display items </button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const mapDispatchToProps = { getAllItems };

function mapStateToProps(state) {
  return {
    itemsById: state.itemsById
  };
}
```

```
export function getAllItems() {
  return dispatch => ({
    type: "GET_ITEMS"
  });
}
```

Comment: Hi David, check my solution and let me know if that helps.

Comment: Thank you @ravibagul91 for your guidance, it helped me go towards the solution

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple problems with your code:

```
const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  actions: state.actions,
  sum: state.sum
});
```

Here you have mapped redux state fields to props `actions` and `sum` - your component won't receive a `state` prop, instead it will receive `actions` and `sum` directly.

so your component really should be:

```
const Button = ({
  actions,
  sum,
}) => (
  <>
    <ul>{actions && actions.map(item => <li>{item}</li>)}</ul>
  </>
);
```

your `mapDispatchToProps` function is not defined correctly. It should be something like this:

```
// ideally you don't want the function names in your component to be the same as the ones you imported so I'm renaming it here: 
import { getAllItems as getAllItemsAction } from "./actions";

// you need to actually `dispatch` the action
const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => ({
  getAllItems: () => dispatch(getAllItemsAction()),
});
```

Your reducer doesn't seem to be defined correctly as well, however you should try to fix the problems I mentioned above first :)

Try not to do too much in one go when you are learning react/redux. I'd recommend reviewing the basics (how the data flow works, how to map state from the redux store to your component, what is an action-creator, etc.).

Answer (score 0):

As you are destructuring the props,

```
const Buttons = ({
  state,
  getAllItems,
  addEventToBeginning,
  addEventToEnd
}) => ( ...
```

You don't have access to `state`, instead you need to directly use `actions` and `sum` like,

```
const Buttons = ({
  actions,   // get the actions directly
  sum,      // get the sum directly 
  getAllItems,
  addEventToBeginning,
  addEventToEnd
}) => (
  <React.Fragment>
    //You cannot print object directly, need to print some values like item.type / item.value
    <ul>{actions && actions.length && actions.map(item => <li>{item.type} {item.value}</li>)}</ul>   
    <button onClick={getAllItems}> Display items </button>
    <button onClick={addEventToBeginning}> addEventToBeginning </button>
    <button onClick={addEventToEnd}> addEventToEnd </button>
  </React.Fragment>
);
```

Your [`mapDispatchToProps`](https://react-redux.js.org/using-react-redux/connect-mapdispatch) should be,

```
const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
  return {
    // dispatching actions returned by action creators
    getAllItems : () => dispatch(getAllItems()),
    addEventToBeginning : () => dispatch(addEventToBeginning()),
    addEventToEnd : () => dispatch(addEventToEnd())
  }
}
```

Or you can make use of `bindActionCreators`,

```
import { bindActionCreators } from 'redux'

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
  return {
    dispatch,
    ...bindActionCreators({ getAllItems, addEventToBeginning, addEventToEnd }, dispatch)
  }
}
```

In `reducer`, `ADD_EVENT_TO_END` should add element to end of the array, but you are adding again at the beginning using `unshift`. You should use `push` which will add element at the end of array,

```
case ADD_EVENT_TO_END:
      const copy2 = { ...state };
      copy2.actions.push(newUnit);  //Add element at the end
      return copy2;
```

Also your `GET_ITEMS` should be as simple as,

```
case GET_ITEMS:
      return state;
```